# Is it feasible to create docker file for each service of my node project?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am learning docker.Somebody tell me what is the best practice to create docker images for node services.Should I create single docker image for whole project or implement one docker image for each api.What should be the best way and why, kindly give the explanation.

Comment: Have you searched on the net?

Comment: Yes i searched but not get any satisfactory solution, why i need to create images for each api and what is the benefit of it.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it feasible to create docker file for each service of my node project?

Yes! If you think you can define different components of your project, separate them and use different *"lean"* containers. I suggest you take a look at this presentation from Jérôme Petazzoni: [Implementing Separation of Concerns with Docker and Containers](https://www.slideshare.net/jpetazzo/implementing-separation-of-concerns-with-docker-and-containers)

---

*from slides 32-34:*

#### Bloated containers

- Containers have all the software required for production
- In dev mode, only essential processes are started
- In prod mode, additional processes run as well
- Problems:

  - bigger containers
  - behavior can differ (because of extra processes)
  - extra processes duplicated between containers
  - hard to test those extra processes in isolation

#### Lean containers

**Principle**

- "Do one thing, do it well"
- One container for the component itself
- One container for logging
- One container for monitoring
- One container for backups
- One container for debugging (when needed)

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good practice to create one single image for different API's. Why ? Because each API has it's own needs, it's own environment variables, maybe different URLs to access different databases and so… Even if the dockerfile is the same for almost all your APIs containers, you may have different needs. The thing with docker is that it saves layers when you build your image, these layers are shared and cached so they can be reused by different services based on the same layers.

My advice is the following:

• If you are a putting in place a **micro-service architecture** with a unique role for each API, create **separate images** for each service

• If you dont care and you are running into a **monolith architecture**, use one **single image**